# IF Internet Explorer use different jQuery function

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function, if-statement, hide

I'm building a home page that is similar in function to www.chanel.com. When you first load the page, I've got a video embedded via HTML5 playing on loop. In the interest of compatibility and ease, I'd like a jQuery function controlling its visibility (hides when links are hovered over) in all browsers except for IE, and an alternative jQuery function for IE only, hiding the video and making an image visible in it's place.

Thanks for your time!

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <video id="vid_home" width="780px" height="520px" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
        <source src="Video/fernando.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="Video/fernando.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
    <img id="img_home" src="Images/home.jpg" alt="Fernando Garibay />
</div>
```

Javascript for Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Opera:

```
// Navigation hover image preview
$('#img_home').css('display', 'none');
$('.nav').hover(function(){
    $('#vid_home').fadeOut(600, function(){
        $('#img_home').fadeIn(800);
    });
});
$('#item1').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/music.jpg');
});
$('#item2').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/photos.jpg');
});
$('#item3').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/biography.jpg');
});
$('#item4').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/discography.jpg');
});
$('#item5').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/contact.jpg');
});
$('#item6').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/blog.png');
});
// Navigation hover image leave
$('#trigger').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#img_home').fadeOut(600, function(){
        $('#vid_home').fadeIn(800)
    });
});
```

Javascript for IE (any version):

```
// Navigation hover image preview
$('#img_vid').css('display', 'none');
$('#item1').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/music.jpg');
});
$('#item2').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/photos.jpg');
});
$('#item3').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/biography.jpg');
});
$('#item4').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/discography.jpg');
});
$('#item5').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/contact.jpg');
});
$('#item6').hover(function(){
    $('#img_home').attr('src', 'Images/blog.png');
});
// Navigation hover image leave without selection
$('#trigger').mouseleave(function(){
    var img = $('#img_home');
    if (img.attr('src') != 'Images/home.jpg'){
        img.fadeOut(600, function(){ 
            img.attr('src','Images/home.jpg');
            img.fadeIn(800);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The video is a red herring, except that you probably should pause and resume playback to conserve resources when it can't be seen. I've made a simple sample showing that all you need is some CSS to get them to be layered. http://jsfiddle.net/HJg6Q/1/

Your code to change the image source is reasonable, though if you have not pre-buffered the images you may get a case where you begin to fade-in the last-loaded image and then it pops to the new image. Very unprofessional. I'd personally suggest a unique `<img>` tag for each image you want to display, and cross-fade them as appropriate.

Comment: Hey Phrogz, thanks for the info. I updated the post with a new approach. I've got the video/img dance set with the new function and it seems more reliable. All that's left with that is making a function to show IE one script and everyone else the other. 

You brought up two really great points that I'd appreciate some explanation on:
Pre-loading the images (found an interesting CSS method. What do you recommend?)
Stopping the video when it's not visible (can't find anything on this.)